# aws conditional automation steps based on python output

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I am using the following automation document (It's only the relevant parts):

```
mainSteps:
  - name extractInfo
    action: 'aws:executeScript'
    outputs:
      - Name: infoMsg
        Selector: $.Payload
        Type: String
    inputs:
      Runtime: python3.6
      Handler: script_handler
      Script: |-
        def script_handler(events, context):
          return "one"
  - name: Branching
    action: 'aws:branch'
    inputs:
      Choices:
        - NextStep: Option1
          Variable: extractInfo.infoMsg
          StringEquals: "one"
        - NextStep: Option2
          Variable: extractInfo.infoMsg
          StringEquals: "two"
      Default: End
```

As you understand I try to use the branching based on python's output.
The problem is that when I run the automation it branches to `End` step (even though you can see it should branch to `Option1`).

I don't have any clue why it's happening, so any help will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I didn't refer to the output in the right syntax, so it should be like this:

```
"{{extractInfo.infoMsg}}"
```